# insert data which is stored in a variable into Postgres database table with c script

Tags: c, postgresql, variables, sql-insert

I have written a c script to insert data into the PostgreSQL table. In the code, I have data that is in buffer variable and I want to write that data into my database. I am trying to insert a variable using “:” but it’s not working. since I have little experience in coding still I'm unable to modify my code to do the job.
I have listed the code part below. Does anyone know how to modify my code to work?

```
res = PQexec(conn, "INSERT INTO pressure(SENSORVAL) VALUES(:buffer)");
    
if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK) 
    do_exit(conn, res);     

PQclear(res);
```

Comment: i have modified my question for understanding

Answer (score 0):

To use parameters in a query, you have to use [`PQexecParams`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-exec.html#id-1.7.3.10.3.3.1.1.1.2). The parameter has to be `$1` in the SQL statement, and you supply the argument in the `paramValues` parameter:

```c
#include <libpq-fe.h>

const char * const paramValues[1] = { "value" };

PGresult *res = PQexecParams(conn,
                             "INSERT INTO pressure (sensorval) VALUES ($1)",
                             1,        /* number of parameters */
                             NULL,     /* parameter types (inferred from context) */
                             paramValues,
                             NULL,     /* parameter lengths (ignored for strings) */
                             NULL,     /* parameter formats (text) */
                             0         /* result format (text) */
                            );
```